# Chat.Read and Chat.ReadWrite Permissions Usage

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-teams

When registering a Graph application in Azure Portal there are permissions for `chat.read` and `chat.readwrite`. Are there corresponding dotnet sdk methods for accessing chat with these permissions enabled?

If not are there plans to support this in the future?

Timelines, etc? If this isn't the correct location to ask this question, please provide a link to the website where this question can be answered.

permissions:

[image: permissions]

Comment: I cannot comment on these particular scopes other than to note that new permissions scopes surface prior new functionality. These scopes take time to propagate so you'll always see them showing up in AAD before you see the functions that use them showing up in Graph.  It's honestly impossible to give an ETA, there are just too many variables (not to mention product teams) when dealing an API as big and broad as Graph.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur I appreciate you taking time to comment! Thanks for the explanation on the propagation of features, that in itself is good info for me.